# Allow manager to edit MySite profile?

Tags: my-site, mysite

This is SP2010. Is there a way to allow managers to edit a user's profile as seen in their My Site profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is little complicated, how many managers you want to give this kind of permission? If one then it really easy, otherwise create a group and add all managers in it then delegate them Manage **Profile Permissions**.

To delegate administration of User Profile service features by using Central Administration

1. Verify that the user account that completes this procedure has the
   following credentials:

The user account that performs this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group or has been delegated permission to administer the User Profile service application that is running in the farm.

- Start SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.

  **For Windows Server 2008 R2:**
  Click Start, click Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Products, and then click SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.

**For Windows Server 2012:**

```
On the Start screen, click SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.
If SharePoint 2013 Central Administration is not on the Start screen:
Right-click Computer, click All apps, and then click SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.
```

- In Central Administration, in the Application Management section,
  click Manage service applications.
- In the list of service applications, click **User Profile Service
  Application**.
- On the Service Applications tab, in the **Operations group**, click
  **Administrators**.
- On the **Administrators for User Profile Service Application** page, type
  or select a user or group account, and then click **Add**.
- In the Permissions for **User /Group**: box, check the feature or
  features for which you want to **delegate Manage Profile**, and then
  click **OK.**

[Delegate administration of User Profile service application features in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721065.aspx)

Alos Check this one

http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/01/sharepoint-user-profile-assistant-field/

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, only the system account can change other people's profiles in 2010. You could write some custom code that impersonates the system account and updates profiles behind the scenes.